# Mathematica Related Book, Website or Github on Bayesian Statistics/Analysis

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I just started working on [Analysis with Mathematica](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3110590131), and I am loving every bit of it.
I was wondering if there is a similar book geared toward bayesian statistics with mathematical?
An alternative might be a series of blog posts that does something similar or a github repository that is well documented doing the something.

Thanks a lot for the feedback, folks.

Comment: What is a "paperback"? Is it an ebook?

Comment: paperback means a hardcopy. They also have an ebook verion

Answer (score 9):

You may be interested in the book by Phil Gregory: [Bayesian Logical Data Analysis](https://www.amazon.nl/Bayesian-Logical-Analysis-Physical-Sciences-ebook/dp/B00E3UR7QS/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_nl_NL=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=1YV3CQVDCFRKH&keywords=phil%20gregory&qid=1668096495&s=books&sprefix=phil%20gregory%2Cstripbooks%2C62&sr=1-2).
The MMA code is available through the publisher's website, under [Resources](https://www.cambridge.org/nl/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/statistics-physical-sciences-and-engineering/bayesian-logical-data-analysis-physical-sciences-comparative-approach-mathematica-support?format=PB).

A completely different approach to Bayesian analysis is by David Blower. He has written 4 books with lots of MMA code. Blower is very principled in his reasoning. You can learn a lot from him - as I did. Here is a [Link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1460938380) to Volume 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. A little old but seeing as Mathematica doesn't change much, I am guessing this will be just up to date.

Comment: I actually had the first two copies of David's book but didn't know there were accompanying MMA code?

Or are you referring to the MMA code in the appendix?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to copy the code manually from the books by retyping. For Volume 4, we are preparing a release on GitHub of all MMA code. I was one of the editors of this volume after David Blower passed away.

Comment: In the intervening time, my own tutorial book "What is your model?" is published on Amazon. It does refer to Mathematica, but it contains no actual code. Here is the [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BTNVFR65).